# add jquery to drupal website

Tags: theming, javascript

I want to add 2 jquery scripts to my website that have to be executed on every page.

[Smoothstate](http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/)

```
<script src="jquery.smoothState.js"></script>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

If i read some websites I don't understand how to add them. I can call the js file's in my .info file or is there an other way? I also read about template_process_html() to add js to my theme but in what file i have to put this?

Can someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to just add it to your theme info file.
That is the easiest way really, since you need them on every  page.

PS: dont forget to clear caches after you added it to your themes info file.